# Binding textboxes to properties of a comboBox.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, data-binding, textbox

I'm using winforms and I've got a comboBox that represents an IQueryable.  Below the combobox is a series of textboxes that I would like to be bound to the currently selected  from the combo box.

Here is my code.

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public DataClassesDataContext DataContext;

    public IQueryable<T> datasource;

    // Ctor
    public TestForm()
    {
    InitializeComponent();

    // L2S data context
    this.DataContext = new DataClassesDataContext();

    // Get the variable for the data source
    this.datasource = this.DataContext.Ts;

    // setup the binding for the combobox
    this.comboBox1.DataSource = this.datasource;
    this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
    this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";

    // assign the databindings of the text boxes to the selectedItem of the combo box    
    // this is where the problem is, afaik
    TId.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.comboBox1.SelectedItem, "Id"));
    TUser.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.comboBox1.SelectedItem, "User"));
    TDescription.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.comboBox1.SelectedItem, "Description"));
}
```

Doing this binds everything, When I change the values in the text boxes, it updates the initially selected item in the combo box just fine.  Even when I change the description, it updates the displayed text in the drop don, all that is great.

However, when I select a different item from the drop down, the text boxes don't bind to that newly selected item, they stay bound to the old one.

Do I need to remove and re-add my bindings every time the selection changes on the combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) rather than directly relying upon the L2S data context.  The binding source uses a concurrency manager to handle all the updating for you  and the L2S does not

Working code:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public DataClassesDataContext DataContext;

    // Incorrect: public IQueryable<T> datasource;
    // Correct:
    public BindingSource TsDataSource;

    // Ctor
    public TestForm()
    {
    InitializeComponent();

    // L2S data context
    this.DataContext = new DataClassesDataContext();

    // Get the variable for the data source
    // Incorrect: this.datasource = this.DataContext.Ts;
    // Correct:
    this.TsDataSource = new BindingSource();
    this.TsDataSource.DataSource = this.DataContext.Ts;

    // setup the binding for the combobox
    this.comboBox1.DataSource = this.TsDataSource;
    this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
    this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";

    // assign the databindings of the text boxes to the selectedItem of the combo box    
    TId.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.TsDataSource, "Id"));
    TUser.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.TsDataSource, "User"));
    TDescription.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.TsDataSource, "Description"));
}
```

More about BindingSource from the [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) (couldnt resist):

> The BindingSource component serves
>   many purposes. First, it simplifies
>   binding controls on a form to data by
>   providing currency management, change
>   notification, and other services
>   between Windows Forms controls and
>   data sources. This is accomplished by
>   attaching the BindingSource component
>   to your data source using the
>   DataSource property. For complex
>   binding scenarios you can optionally
>   set the DataMember property to a
>   specific column or list in the data
>   source. You then bind controls to the
>   BindingSource. All further interaction
>   with the data is accomplished with
>   calls to the BindingSource component.
>   For examples on how the BindingSource
>   can simplify the binding process, see
>   How to: Bind Windows Forms Controls to
>   DBNull Database Values and How to:
>   Handle Errors and Exceptions that
>   Occur with Databinding. Navigation and
>   updating of the data source is
>   accomplished through methods such as
>   MoveNext, MoveLast, and Remove.
>   Operations such as sorting and
>   filtering are handled through the Sort
>   and Filter properties. For more
>   information on using sorting and
>   filtering with the BindingSource, see
>   How to: Sort and Filter ADO.NET Data
>   with the Windows Forms BindingSource
>   Component.

Answer (score 1):

My original answer was wrong, and admittedly I do not fully understand what all is happening here, but I have a solution which is working.

Basically you need to grab the `BindingManagerBase` from the `BindingContext` and use it to enforce databinding on each `SelectedItemChanged` event.

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public DataClassesDataContext DataContext;

    public IQueryable<T> datasource;
    private BindingManagerBase bmComboBoxSelectedItem;

    // Ctor
    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // L2S data context
        this.DataContext = new DataClassesDataContext();

        // Get the variable for the data source
        this.datasource = this.DataContext.Ts;

        // setup the binding for the combobox
        this.comboBox1.DataSource = this.datasource;
        this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
        this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";

        // assign the databindings of the text boxes to the selectedItem of the combo box    
        // this is where the problem is, afaik
        TId.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.comboBox1, "SelectedItem.Id"));
        TUser.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.comboBox1, "SelectedItem.User"));
        TDescription.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.comboBox1, "SelectedItem.Description"));

        bmComboBoxSelectedItem = this.BindingContext[this.comboBox1, "SelectedItem"];
    }

    // make sure you assign this event on the forms designer or your preferred method
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bmCustomers.ResumeBinding();
    }
}
```

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.aspx) helped a lot.

Comment: I get this exception "DataMember property 'SelectedItem' cannot be found on the DataSource."

Comment: I've also tried binding to a member variable and onchange on the drop down, i reassign that variable to the currently selected one.  That too causes my initial problem.  So, I don't think this is the solution I need

Comment: Hopefully these changes will help you get started.  I really don't fully understand it yet, but this is what I came up with by playing with it and using the linked MSDN article.

Comment: Awesome, I will follow up on monday for sure, +1 for now, thanks again

Comment: ok so i've since learned to just add the datasource and let the designer wire up all your databindings for you.  I'll post some of the code that the designer writes for you.