# C# combo box value and display using invoke method

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox, task

I am using [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), and I have a combo box with the values:

> Apple 
> Oranges 
> Pairs

My text box contains values 1, 2 and 3,

apple = 1 and oranges = 2 and pairs = 3.

This relation is in my table on SQL, fields Account and Name. How do I change the value of the textbox to = 2 if the combo box is selected as oranges?

Basically this is reference to a program I'm working on that has an account combo box that displays the accounts names (user friendly). I need the names ID account number to then be displayed in the text box. From this text box I can then pass the value into my stored procedure that will get all the information on that account.

### Update

The above text is out of date. See below!

A note to add is that my code gets the account details and populates my combo box.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or does this require joining in C# similar to SQL joins on tables?

Or without using a text box at all, basically my combo would have 2 fields orange, 2 but only display oranges to the user, but my other method uses the second field 2.

OK, so this part adds the acc field to the combo box.

```
{
    SqlCommand accountFill = new SqlCommand("SELECT name, acc FROM dbo.Customer", conn1);
    SqlDataReader readacc = accountFill.ExecuteReader();

    while (readacc.Read())
    {
        AddItem(readacc.GetString(0).ToString(), readacc, "name", "acc");
    }
    conn1.Close();
}
```

Add item is an invoke method used by my task.

```
private void AddItem(string value, Object dataSource, string name, string acc)
{
    if (accCollection.InvokeRequired)
    {
        accCollection.Invoke(new Action<string,Object,string,string>(AddItem), new Object[] { value });
    }
    else
    {
        //accCollection.Items.Add(value);
        accCollection.DataSource = dataSource;
        accCollection.DisplayMember = name;
        accCollection.ValueMember = acc;
    }
}
```

ERROR complex databinding accepts as a datasource iether an i.list or an i.list source at datasource.

Comment: Or even Asp pages - webforms or MVC?

Comment: It's such a broad question that people will have difficulty in giving you the exact answer that you may want. Simply put your application should have a data layer that deals with all of your database interaction. This layer then provides data classes to your main application, business logic using a defined interface. The data class itself can contain the user readable Username and the UserID (from your datatable). These are then bound in someway to your UI interface, whic should be decoupled as much as possible from the business logic. It's tempting to place DB access code directly into the UI

Comment: Here's a similar post that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209290/binding-textboxes-to-properties-of-a-combobox-selecteditem

Comment: @ChrisBD Yes if this was an MVC approach, but as it was a old Winforms Approach Applying MVC For the application Wasn't wanted or needed by the boss. (had this of been asp.net MVC app, then of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) class has two properties `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`. You need to set the `DisplayMember` property to the Names of your table or data, i. e. orange, apple, etc... ,and set the `ValueMember` property to the Id's of them:

```
combobox1.Datasource = readacc;
combobox.DisplayMember = 'name';
combobox.ValueMember = 'acc';
```

All you need then is just use the two properties `SelectedValue` to get the Id or `SelectedText` to get the value. For example, you could get the id of the selected item by using [`ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) Event like this:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e)
{
    textbox2.text = int.parse(combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

or you can get the select text like:

```
textbox2.text = combobox1.SelectedText;
```

Comment: heres where i add the account from the query,  combobox.Items.Add(value);

Comment: are you saying i wont need to have a textbox?  that would be great.  basically my combo would have 2 fields orange,2 but only display oranges to the user , but my other method uses the second field 2.

Comment: @StevenSmith All you need is just set `combobox.DisplayMember = value` and `combobox.ValueMember = Id` then just use the two properties `SelectedValue` to get the Id or `SelectedText` to get the value, If it is not clear i can give you a complete example on how to populate the data from database into combobox and yes you won't need the textbox at all you can get or set the id and value without textbox.

Comment: ive added some code from my class so you can see whats going on. would you replace the additem(tostring) with selected value?  sorry could you give me a example using the small bit off code i provided?

Comment: reson i ask is due to my code using the thread.tasks, as you see i pass the additem string using the invoke method i made  to populate my combo box

Comment: @StevenSmith just set the datasource property of the combobox to the sqldatareader like: `combobox1.Datasource = readacc; combobox.DisplayMember = 'name'; combobox.ValueMember = 'acc';` see my edit

Comment: ohhhh i see so i can set the datasource to that of my execute reader? didnt know i could do that hehe.  then set the values etc.  ok this is great but then how do i pass this to my invoke method? as you can see i use additem invoke method, as i do not call the combo box there, i call it in my invoke method.  again this is due to using the thread.task

Comment: @StevenSmith In your code the `Invoke` method all what it do is take a delegate `System.Delegate` which is `AddItem` and a return type `System.Object` so i didn't now what `AddItem` do in your code but i think it is not a problem

Comment: ive updated my ;post to show what i have attempted so far, i get an arror saying its does not know what acc is

Comment: If `AddItem` just add the items to the combobox then get red of it, there will be no need for it.

Comment: i need it as it is my invoke method.  like i said im using thread.task so i must have all control handles performed by the invoke method.  ive added more code to my post

Comment: I Don't understand why you are still in need to the invoke method to add an item to the combobox collection, but any way you can't set the datasource in the AddItem method you need to set it after the sqlcommand or outside the invoke method.

Comment: yeh thats the big problem, if i dont use a invoke method to use my combo box control, it wont work since i use a task to get the results.

Comment: What is this task? and why you need it?

Comment: ok the task is used to run my query that gets all the data belonging to that account, the data involved is HUUUUGEEE so my controls and form freeze, so i use a task and put the SQL HUUGE query in there which leaves my form alone.  To do this i must wrap an invoke method around any handles to controls that the sql will use.

Comment: Ok, Sorry for that, but i havn't used `Invoke` before but from your description i think you need to put the datasource after the sqldatareader and set the valuemember and display member after it them you will need something like `ShowAccounts` to get the data belong to that account not to AddItem thats all what i can say to you, you won't need to AddItem in the invoke method just do other functionality on it like ShowAccounts

Comment: im thinking of reposting this with the stuff ive altered.

Comment: thanks for your advice, ive opened up a new question, that takes your advice. ill flag you for the answer ty!

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("ListItem");
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));

    dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{1,"apple"});
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{2,"oranges"});
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{3,"pairs"});

    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember="Id";

    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Id");
```

or

```
    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1; //for initial step;

void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: ahhhh i see so instead of feeding my results into the combo, i feed it into a datatable, then feed that into my combo selecting the value and the display?

Comment: when you change your selection the value in textbox change automatically

Comment: only problem i have is im using invoke methods because of tasks.  Ive posted some code at my attempt to get things working