# C# Textbox with databinding is not updating

Tags: c#, binding, textbox, refresh

I have a classic Form with 3 textboxes and 1 combobox. Combobox shows list of Users and 3 textboxes should contain details about the selected user in the combobox. For selected user I have a special attribute (as shown below) which I am using as data source. This is ok only on the first run. When the form is shown, changing user in combobox has no effect.

```
public partial class UserAdministration : Form
{
    private readonly DataManager _dataManager = DataManager.Instance;
    private User _selectedUser;

    public UserAdministration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserAdministration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddUsers();
        textBoxName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _selectedUser, "Name");
        textBoxSurname.DataBindings.Add("Text", _selectedUser, "Surname");
        textBoxPassword.DataBindings.Add("Text", _selectedUser, "Password");
    }

    private void AddUsers()
    {
        var users = _dataManager.UserProvider.GetAll().Select(pair => pair.Value).ToList();
        comboBoxUsers.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = users };
        comboBoxUsers.DisplayMember = "ListViewText";
        if (users.Count > 0)
            comboBoxUsers.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void comboBoxUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _selectedUser = comboBoxUsers.SelectedItem as User;
    }
}
```

What am I missing? What is wrong with data binding?

Comment: What is the combobox data source update mode set to?

Comment: Combobox data source type is [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f.aspx), so it can not have update mode, or?

Comment: I missed that you were binding directly using an object. The issue is with the concurrency manager. See if this answer helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209290/binding-textboxes-to-properties-of-a-combobox-selecteditem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to bind your datasource to cb use this code:

```
comboBoxUsers.DataSource = users (directly to you datasource);
```

to bind the same data to textbox do it like this:

```
textbox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", users, "username", true);
```

the only point is, that you need to link both controls to the same ds instance

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Btw, internally it uses Combobox.SelectedItem, right?

Answer (score 3):

I have a form with ONLY a textbox that I wanted to bind to database column.

When I used the 'properties' settings to data-bind that textbox to one column, it created the `bindingSource1` and table adapter for me.

When I clicked the SAVE button, I simply added `bindingSource1.EndEdit();` and then it saved correctly to the database.

Comment: In my case, I had no BindingSource, and because my textbox had not lost focus when my Save() function was called, the binding had not been synced.  I had to call `TextBox1.DataBindings.Item(NameOf(TextBox1.Text)).WriteValue()` to force a sync.